# Find and replace a string with double quotation marks, comma and colon

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find and replace a string with double quotation marks, a comma and a colon, but I'm getting a error, I thought it was easier then it looks, but sadly I'm wrong.

What I tried so far is:

```
Cells.Replace What:=""Gorilla": "",", Replacement:=""Gorilla": """, LookAt:=xlPart
```

So the word/string I want to replace is `"Gorilla": "",`

The expected outcome should be `"Gorilla": ""`  The difference is this one is *(without comma)*

**EDIT: (to make my question more clear)**

**The yellow and green highlighted parts mean nothing and is just for example purposes.*

**Everything happens in column A, column D is just for example purposes.*

The data looks like this in the screenshot. I have to search for the exact same string `"Gorilla": "",` to replace it with `"Gorilla": ""`.

There isn't really an order in which row this part `"Gorilla": ""` can be, it can be on any row, but the string stays the same.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Your issue is correctly escaping the quotes. Try `What:="""Gorilla"": """",",  Replacement:="""Gorilla"": """""`

Comment: Omg thank you @chrisneilsen you should post this as an answer so I can give credits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution provided by: **@chris neilsen**

**Solution:**

```
What:="""Gorilla"": """",",  Replacement:="""Gorilla"": """""
```

**Solution in code:**

```
Cells.Replace What:="""Gorilla"": """",", Replacement:="""Gorilla"": """"", LookAt:=xlPart
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the start and end characters of your target string is always double quotes, then this custom function should work. You could include this in your macro if it's part of some other procedure.

```
Function fixString(theString As String) As String
Const startText As String = """"
Const endText As String = """"
Dim startPlace As Long, endPlace As Long

startPlace = InStr(1, theString, startText)
endPlace = InStrRev(theString, endText, -1)
fixString = Mid(theString, startPlace, endPlace)

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @PGSystemTester, I appreciate the answer, but all my words end with ": "", and only from this specific word must the comma be removed. The word can be random in any row, that's why I'm looking more for a automatic find and replace answer so I don't have to do anything manually.

Comment: Sorry but not very clear what you're trying to accomplish. Why don't you include like 5-10 examples of what you start with and what you're expecting (as you did in your question) and explain briefly on each line what's being taken into account to achieve the desired outcome in each example (As you did in the question with the missing comma).

Comment: Hi @PGSystemTester I have updated my question!

Comment: Why is the expected outcome in row 5 include a comma at the end?

Comment: Sorry I don't know why, this is the output of a JSON file opened with Excel.

Comment: I'm trying to be patient with you as I felt bad about trashing your post the other night, but you are really not being clear nor is it obvious what you're trying to do. As i stated, please show the desired starting value and the expected outcome. You did that in your question. Now you've got a JSON list... what are you trying to do with it? What would be the perfect outcome?

Also... why are you highlighting something if it "mean nothing "

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Really appreciated!

Comment: So you only wish to replace cell instances that contain `"Gorilla": "",` with `"Gorilla": ""` ? All other values are good? I think I was presuming you needed a more dynamic solution based on yesterday. Oh well, glad it works.

Comment: Yeah everything else is good, it was just this one which needed to be different, I thought I explained it clearly, but apparently not, sorry :)!